# Most basic rails controller implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I dont get this basic implementation.

models

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :listing
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base      
  belongs_to :player
end
```

Player controller

```
  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    @listing = @player.listing.new
  end
```

routes

```
  resources :listings
  devise_for :players

  match "players/:id" => "players#show"
```

error

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why I wouldn't to create a new listing from my player show page. I think my routes may need to be nested but that doesn't explain the error.

I've been at this for two years and when I read the guides I feel like I understand completely, but when I set out to do it on my own I'm misunderstanding the most basic implementation of rendering this simple view. I am out of mind mind frustrated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@player.listing` is not set, yet. If you are making a new item on a `has_one` relationship, you will want to use `@player.build_listing`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one